# programatically forcing function keys on Mac touch bar

Tags: macos, nstouchbar, macbookpro-touch-bar

I know that users can set specific apps to run with the function keys active on the touch bar by default in their system keyboard prefs as per https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207240. But is there anyway for a developer to request this from within their app? I browsed the Apple developer docs on this subject but did not see any way to do this, if it's there it's well hidden - seems like Apple is more into encouraging devs to forget about the existence of the f-keys and embrace the dynamic functionality of the touch bar.